# How to send the information in in this form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have created this Bootstrap Form for my website so that clients can contact me. i am using PHP to send the form to my email address. The form gets sent to my email address but when i receive it, the information put into the text fields of the form doesn't show up.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
<?PHP
 
 
 
 /* Subject & Email Variables */
 
 $emailSubject = 'Photography Quote';
 $webMaster = 'ryanandelissa@seawardphotography.com';
 
 /* Gathering Data Variables*/
 
 $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
 $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $hdyhau = $_POST['hdyhau'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 
 $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $firstname <br>
Last Name:  $lastname <br>
Email: $email <br>
How Did You Hear About Us?: $hdyhau <br>
Message: $message <br>
EOD;

 $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
 $headers = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
 
 /* Results Rendered As HTML */
 
 $theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Us</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Contact.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
 
 /*logo*/

img{
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 
}

/*navbar*/

#wrap{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-right: 48px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 
}

.navbar li a{
 display: block;
}

.navbar li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: left;
 
}

.navbar a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #9c9c9c;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px;
 background-color: white;
}

.navbar li ul{
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 
}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover{
 color: black;
}

.navbar li:hover ul{
 display: block;
} 

.navbar li ul li {
 display: block;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Lora' serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type=button]{
 border: 2px solid #9c9c9c;
 background-color: white;
 color: #9c9c9c; 
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

input[type=button]:hover{
 background-color: #9c9c9c;
 color: white;
 border: 2px #9c9c9c;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 41px;
}


/*footer*/

footer{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-top: 30px;
}

 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
             
             <img src="Images/NewLogoBlack.png" class="img-responsive" width="250px" height="250px">
         
         </div>
          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
         
         
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">

   <div id="wrap">
   <ul class="navbar">
 
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li> 
   <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="wedding.html">WEDDING</a></li>
      <li><a href="Love.html">LOVE</a></li>
      
   </ul>         
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html">US</a></li>
   </ul>         
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="NewBlogPage3.html">STORIES</a></li>
     <li><a href="Archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>      
   <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>   
   </div>   

             
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
       
       
       
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        
<h1>Thank you for your inquiry. We'll be in contact shortly.</h1>
        
</div>   
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
       
<form action="Instagram.html">
<input type="button" value="HOME">
</form> 


<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
         
 
        
       
       
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><footer>All images Copyright © Seaward Photography 2016. Based in San Diego, California. Available for destinations worldwide.</footer></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>

            




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo($theResults);


            

?>
```

```css
/*logo*/

img{
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 
}

/*navbar*/

#wrap{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-right: 48px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 
}

.navbar li a{
 display: block;
}

.navbar li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: left;
 
}

.navbar a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #9c9c9c;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px;
 background-color: white;
}

.navbar li ul{
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 
}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover{
 color: black;
}

.navbar li:hover ul{
 display: block;
} 

.navbar li ul li {
 display: block;
}

/*image*/

.contact img{
 width: 70%;
}


/* form */

.form label{
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-left: 400px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 padding-right: 189px;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 
}


input, textarea{
 font: 1em "Lora" sans-serif;
 width:300px;
 
 
}

textarea{
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 5em;
 resize: vertical;
 
}

input[type=submit]{
 border: 2px solid #9c9c9c;
 background-color: white;
 color: #9c9c9c; 
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

input[type=submit]:hover{
 background-color: #9c9c9c;
 color: white;
 border: 2px #9c9c9c;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 44px;
}


/*footer*/

footer{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-top: 10px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Us</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Contact.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
 
 img{
  padding-bottom: 30px;
 }
 
 .contact-form{
  padding: 20px;
 }
 
 label{
  font-family: "Lora" serif;
  font-weight: 300;
 }
 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
             
             <img src="Images/NewLogoBlack.png" class="img-responsive" width="250px" height="250px">
         
         </div>
          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
         
         
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">

   <div id="wrap">
   <ul class="navbar">
 
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li> 
   <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="wedding.html">WEDDING</a></li>
      <li><a href="Love.html">LOVE</a></li>
      
   </ul>         
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html">US</a></li>
   </ul>         
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="NewBlogPage3.html">STORIES</a></li>
     <li><a href="Archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>      
   <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>   
   </div>   

             
            </div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
 
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
         <div class="img-list">    
             
          
    
      <img src="Images/ContactImage.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="750px" height="auto" />
          
      

         </div>    
            </div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div> 
       
       
               
        <form method="post" action="Contact%20Form.php" >
   <div class="contact-form">
    
         
     <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-6 ">     
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="hdyhau">How Did You Hear About Us?</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hdyhau">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>  


        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND!" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div> 
     </div>   
    </form>

 
 
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><footer>All images Copyright © Seaward Photography 2016. Based in San Diego, California. Available for destinations worldwide.</footer></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>

            




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a typo `$headers = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);` notice what's missing here? Yeah; a dot and the "chainlink" broke. Typos are *off-topic*. Here `$headers .= mail...` - *Enjoy*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank YOOOOOUUUU!!! it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this was a typo, missing a dot/concatenate in the following and "*breaking the chain, as it were*":

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
        ^ Missing a dot/concatenate and is "broken"
```

that should have read as:

```
$headers .= mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

You really should be checking for empty fields, as you risk in receiving empty emails.

For example and being a serverside method which is best to also use should a user disable JS, the following does that and checks if the submit button is also clicked:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

    if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) 
    && !empty($_POST['lastname']) 
    && !empty($_POST['email']) 
    && !empty($_POST['hdyhau']) 
    && !empty($_POST['message']) )

    {

    // Send the mail here

    }

}
```

---

You could also use the (HTML5) `required` attribute for your inputs.

I.e.:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" required>
```

Also look into the following for a JS method:

- [Mark error in form using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361517/mark-error-in-form-using-bootstrap)
- [how to disable a send button if fields empty bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055533/how-to-disable-a-send-button-if-fields-empty-bootstrap)
- [Validate input text in bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968361/validate-input-text-in-bootstrap-modal)